# Converting JSON data into Chart.js array from strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, chart.js

I'm pulling data from a JSON file stored as a Javascript variable:

```js
var jsonFile = {
  "profiles": [{
      "time": 0,
      "conc": 0.15,
      "fitted": 0.1,
      "non": 0,
      "prior": 30,
      "missed": 2.9,
      "wrong": 2.9,
      "mix": 0.15,
      "temp": 0.015,
      "gel": 0.03,
      "data": 4
    },
    {
      "time": 1,
      "conc": 11,
      "fitted": 10,
      "non": 5,
      "prior": 35,
      "missed": 2.35,
      "wrong": 25,
      "mix": 11,
      "temp": 1.1,
      "gel": 2.2,
      "data": 4
    },
    {...}
  }];
```

I pull the data pairs I need for the specific line in the chart using the `map()` method:

`var dataPairs = jsonFile.profiles.map(function(e) {
     return '{x:' + e.time + ', y:' + e.fitted + '}';
});`

And then I tried to format it like an array needed for Chart.js

`var dataPairs2 = '[' + dataPairs + ']';`

So for the chart `data` line, I would call `dataPairs2`. After looking at `console.log(dataPairs2)`, I realized it's not being treated as an array. `dataPairs` *is* and array, but each entry is a string, so calling that instead for the `data` line doesn't work either.

So, I'm trying to figure out how to convert `dataPairs2` into an array. `JSON.Parse()` doesn't seem to work because it's not a standard format (I'm guessing), and I don't think I can use `split()` with commas as a delimiter because each array entry contains a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for but you could simply return an `Object` instead of a `String`. Therefore return:

```
{x: e.time, y: e.fitted}
```

instead of:

```
'{x:' + e.time + ', y:' + e.fitted + '}'
```

in your mapping.

Here is the code:

```js
const jsonFile = {profiles:[{time:0,conc:.15,fitted:.1,non:0,prior:30,missed:2.9,wrong:2.9,mix:.15,temp:.015,gel:.03,data:4},{time:1,conc:11,fitted:10,non:5,prior:35,missed:2.35,wrong:25,mix:11,temp:1.1,gel:2.2,data:4}]};


const dataPairs = jsonFile.profiles.map(e => ({x: e.time, y: e.fitted}) )

console.log(dataPairs)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just format them in such a way in a first call to map. Instead of using map to produce array of stings, use it to produce array of objects.

```
jsonFile.profiles.map(v => ({ x: v.time, y: v.fitted }) );
```

```js
var jsonFile = {
  "profiles": [
    { "time": 0, "conc": 0.15, "fitted": 0.1, "non": 0, "prior": 30, "missed": 2.9, "wrong": 2.9, "mix": 0.15, "temp": 0.015, "gel": 0.03, "data": 4 },
    { "time": 1, "conc": 11, "fitted": 10, "non": 5, "prior": 35, "missed": 2.35, "wrong": 25, "mix": 11, "temp": 1.1, "gel": 2.2, "data": 4 }
]};

const d = jsonFile.profiles.map(v => ({ x: v.time, y: v.fitted }) );

console.log(d);
```